# How to write the Taylor expansion of $f(x+h)$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The Taylor series of function $f(x)$ around $x_0$ is $$f(x)= f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)}{2!}(x-x_0)^2+ \frac{f'''(x_0)}{3!}(x-x_0)^3+\cdots,$$ and found out that the Taylor series of $f(x+h)$ is $$f(x+h)= f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{f''(x)}{2!}h^2+ \frac{f'''(x)}{3!}h^3+\cdots.$$
I can't seem to prove this last equation, assuming that $x_0=0$, for example. How does $f(0)$ turn out to be $f(x)$?

Comment: If you leave the whole infinite sum of terms it's not an approximation. It's only an approximation if you truncate the series.

Answer (score 8):

I'll rewrite the second equation to prevent confusion with identical variable names:

$$f(a+h)\approx f(a)+f'(a)h+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}h^2+ \frac{f'''(a)}{3!}h^3+\cdots.$$

Now, take $x_0 = a$, $x = a+h$, so that $x - x_0 = (a+h)-a = h$, and substitute all this into the first equation to obtain the second one.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series, the Taylor series of a real-  or complex-valued function $f(x)$ that is infinitely differentiable function at a real or complex number $x=a$ is the  power series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left.\frac {d^{(n)}(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=a}\, \frac{(x-a)^{n}}{n!},$$ Does it make sense to say the Taylor series of a  real- or  complex-valued function$f(x+h)$ that is an infinitely differentiable function at a real or  complex number $x+h=x$ is the power series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left.\frac {d^{(n)}(x+h)}{d(x+h)^{(n)}}\right|_{x+h=x}\,\frac{h ^{n}}{n!}?$$

Comment: @lisyarus I know that $f'(a)$ is a nice shorthand for derivatives, but in this case can you please be explicit about which variable you are differentiating wrt? Put another way, is $f'(a)=\frac{df}{dh}\big\rvert_{h=a}$?

Comment: @MichaelLevy When we write $x=a$ here, $a$ is taken to be a predetermined constant, and $x$ is variable. You are conflating them to be the same.

Comment: @Divide1918, Hi again. Can you go a bit further and write out the mathematics?

Comment: @MichaelLevy Th expression in the answer above is given by taking $h=x-a$ or $x=a+h$. What it actually says is that the Taylor series at $x=a$ approximates the function value at another point, in this case $x=a+h$. But it does not mean $x=a=a+h$. This is similar to evaluating the function value at several points, given a function $f(x)$, you can evaluate $f(x)$ at $x=1$, and you can also evaluate it at $x=-1/2$, but that doesn’t mean $1=-1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

You just replace $x_0$ with $x$ and $x$ with $x+h$. This replacement means now you are saying $f$ is differentiable at $x$ i.e you can approximate the function at points close to $x$ using the Taylor expansion. Well, if $h$ is small enough, $x+h$ is close enough to $x$ to use the expansion. And then it falls out from the replacement above. Also, the comment by @Benedict is absolutely correct.

Comment: If we replace $x$ with $x+h$ and then $x_0$ with $x$, we write from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series, that the Taylor series of a real or complex-valued function $f (x+h)$ that is infinitely differentiable at a real or complex number $h=0$ is the power series
$$f(x+h)= f^{(0)}(x)+f^{(1)}\,h +\frac{f^{(2)}(x )}{2!}\,  h^2+\cdots.$$ Does it make sense to say that we have a "Taylor series of a real or complex-valued function $f (x+h)$ that is infinitely differentiable at a real or complex number $h=0$?"

Comment: @MichaelLevy In the analogue, $h$ should be $x-a$, so $a=x-h$.

Comment: @Divide1918, Hi. Can you go a bit further and write out the mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

To show
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f^\prime(x)h+\frac{f''(x)}{2!}h^2+\frac{f'''(x)}{3!}h^3+\cdots , \tag 1$$
we only need to show the LHS of eq(1) is equal to the RHS of eq(1) for every possible value of $x$, namely,
$$f\left( a+h \right) =f(a)+f^\prime(a)h+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}h^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}h^3+\cdots \tag 2$$
for all $a$.

To see this, recall we have the Taylor expansion for $f(x)$ around $x=a$ to be
$$f(x)=f(a)+f^\prime(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+\cdots  \tag 3$$
Therefore, replacing $x$ with $x+h$ in the above equation we have one reasonable(a more familiar form) Taylor expansion for $f(x+h)$ to be
$$f(x+h)=f(a)+f^\prime(a)(x+h-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x+h-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x+h-a)^3+\cdots \tag 4$$
Now, replacing $x$ with $a$ in the above equation, we have
$$f(a+h)=f(a)+f^{\prime}(a)h+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}h^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}h^3+\cdots $$
which is the same as eq(2) for all $a$.